# insert data with many to many relation in Laravel Eloquent

Tags: laravel, many-to-many, eloquent-relationship

I have created Many To Many relationships on both levels (database and Models) for (User) and (Role) Models, now how can I assign many roles to the user id = 2 for instance: like below?

```
       $user = User::find(2);
       ????
        return view('index', compact(''));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using `attach` and insert array for multiple roles

```
$roleId = [1, 2, 3];
$user->roles()->attach($roleId);
```

There's also `sync` method, the difference is `sync` remove all roles associated by user only if its not included in array of roleId

```
// User has role_id 1, 2, 3
$roleId = [1, 3];
$user->roles()->sync($roleId); // Role id 2 removed
```

[Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#updating-many-to-many-relationships)